# If each $x\in A\subseteq X$ has an open nbhd $U_a$ such that $U_a\cap A$ is closed in $U_a$, then $U\cap\overline{A}=A$ for some open $U\subseteq X$

Tags: general-topology

I'm learning topology for first time and I found a problem I don't understand yet:

> $X$ is a topological space, $A\subseteq X$ a subspace such that for all $a\in A$, there is an open set $U_a \ni a$ such that $U_a\cap A$ is closed in $U_a$. I'm asked to exhibit $U$ open such that $U\cap \overline{A}=A$.

Any hint? I'm confused with where things are open, or how to get an open set in $X$.

Comment: Exhibit? Do you mean prove?

Comment: Exhibit an example with that property. I guess prove there is such an $U$. Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $U=\bigcup _{a\in A} U_a$.

Clearly $U\cap \overline A \supseteq A$.

Now for the other inclusion. Suppose for a contradiction that there exists $x\in U\cap (\overline A \setminus A)$.  There exists $a\in A$ such that $x\in U_a\cap (\overline A \setminus A)$. Then $x$ demonstrates that $U_a\cap A$ is not closed in $U_a$.